# How can I use value in .properties file for choice parameters in Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries

I would like to know how I write Jenkinsfile to set the contents of the following properties file for choice param.

resources/platform.properties

```
windows10 22h2
windows10 21h2
windows8.1
windows8
```

Jenkinsfile

```
@Library('test-library') _
pipeline{
   agent any
   parameters {
choice choices: *******, description:
'Choose your favorite distribution', name: 'dist'}
}
```

I want to set the value of the properties file for choices: *******. I could read the contents of the properties file with
vars/getVariable.groovy

```
def call(Map config = [:] {
String props = "['" +  libraryResource("$(config.name)")+ "']"
bat "${props}"
return props
}
```

But I am quite not sure how can I use the return from JenkinsFile...
Should I try another way to achieve this?
Can you please give me some advice?